# Why myeclipse closed suddenly after I modified a perspective?

Tags: perspective, myeclipse

I modified a perspective before the myeclipse crashed.
I guess that is the reason.
Could you give me a actual ?

If I have syntax error in my question , I'm so sorry for my poor English.

Comment: There is not enough information to determine the problem. Which perspective were you changing, what did you change, and was there any error message associated with the crash? You may have a Java dump file or there may be error messages in the MyEclipse workspace log file (the log file is named .log and is in the .metadata folder of your workspace.

Comment: **EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7c9309d8, pid=3612, tid=5508**. This is what I see in the log file. And I changed the perspective named _Myeclipse java enterprise perspective_.I close some views in the perspective,and adjust some view's size. There is no error message when it crashed.

Comment: May be some Java issue. There might be a dump file associated with the crash in your home folder or temp folder. It doesn't look like you're doing anything unusual. Does the crash occur when you try to save the perspective? Which release of MyEclipse? Which version/update of Java (update 40 seemed to have some problems)? Which operating system? 32-bit or 64-bit? Is there any related message in the .log file that I mentioned?